# How do I alert multiple results with ajax from json arrray

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I have this query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ship_data WHERE id = $ship") or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows = $r; 
echo json_encode($rows);
}
```

And this bit of ajax to return the results

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "ship=" + ship,
            cache: false,
            url: "/getdata.php",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.carrier);
            }
        });
```

If there is just one result in the array it works, if the array has multiple results in the array nothing is alerted.

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` extension, it's being deprecated. [Notice the red box](http://www.php.net/mysql_connect), use `PDO` or `mysqli_*` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `while` loop to...

```
$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

And your JavaScript should *always* iterate over `data` with `$.each()`.